# What could be the reason for .on throwing Uncaught TypeError using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, input, typeerror

I have created this working fiddle, but when I try to use the code in a Drupal installation it gives me `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function` on line 5 `jQuery('#input_manual').on('keyup change paste', function(e){`

Usually I can get around these problems by replacing `$` with `jQuery`, but not in this case (if you have a better method – which I bet you do – please let me know). Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Could it be that it clashes with some Drupal related script etc., if so – how do I avoid that?

[See working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/lennyekberg/0gveba7w/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('double input ready');
    //only hide second input if javascript is available
    jQuery("#autocopy_wrap").hide();
    jQuery('#input_manual').on('keyup change paste', function(e){
        jQuery('#input_autocopy').val(jQuery(this).val())
        //debug to see if input is registered through second input field
        console.log(jQuery('#input_autocopy').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: on() function was added in JQuery version 1.7 onwards, please check the version of jQuery being used.

Comment: Probably jQuery version you are using is ancient.

Comment: As above. If you change the version of jQuery in the fiddle to 1.6.4 (pre `on()`) Then you see the error you describe: http://jsfiddle.net/9fqjjkou/. You shouldl really upgrade jQuery as the version you're using now is at least 4 years out of date.

Comment: Damn, you're right of course. The site had 1.4.4....